# Complex comment-start (and end) sequence

Tags: major-mode, comment, syntax-table

As far as I understand there is syntax flags only for comment delimiters made up of two characters but if I have comment delimiters of length greater than two characters is it possible to change syntax table accordingly? And if not, how can I resolve this kind of situation? Just change colors and indentation of comment block and forget about syntax table?

Comment: You can try digging in a mode like `html-mode`, which uses more complex comments.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, ah, of course, I completely forgot about all those languages with which I am not very familiar (there is also ruby I think). Thanks, I'll gonna check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case if someone seeks for an answer, as [@DoMiNeLa10](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12563/dominela10) suggested, I looked in html-mode and ruby-mode and realised that we can set `syntax-propertize-function` which is

> intended to be used by major modes to install a function which applies
>   syntax-table properties in some mode-appropriate way.

So it would be something like this:

```
(setq-local syntax-propertize-function
    (syntax-propertize-rules ("complex regexp comment-start" (0 "< b")))
    (syntax-propertize-rules ("complex regexp comment-end"   (0 "> b"))))
```

In case if regexp contains some groups you need to precise which group to use starting with 1 (0 is reserved for whole expression).

Comment: After setting the ```syntax-propertize-function``` with the above, should the comments get ```font-lock-comment-face``` applied? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69265/after-setting-syntax-propertize-function-comment-is-not-being-fontified-with-co