# Keyword as comment ender (and starter)

Tags: major-mode, comment, syntax

In my [previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34865/complex-comment-start-and-end-sequence) I asked about complex `comment-start` sequence and I think I figured it out, but now I have another problem. Let say we have this mode:

```
(defconst test-font-lock-keywords
  '(("\\<\\(nop\\|end\\)\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face))
  "Expressions to highlight.")

(defvar test-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\; "<" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">;" st)
    st)
  "Syntax table.")

(defun test-syntax-propertize (start end)
  (funcall (syntax-propertize-rules
            ("\\<\\(s\\)tart\\>" (1 "< b"))
            ("\\<en\\(d\\)\\>"   (1 "> b")))
           start end))

(define-derived-mode test-mode prog-mode "Test"
  (setq-local comment-start ";")
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(test-font-lock-keywords))
  (setq-local syntax-propertize-function #'test-syntax-propertize)
  "Test major mode.")
```

So we have two instructions `nop` and `end`, but `end` is also set as comment ender and if there is no `start` before `end` I'd like to set `keyword-face` but it does not work, `end` instruction don't change color at all. I understand why it's happening, but I'm new in elisp and don't know how things work in detail so I can not fix it. Any advice will be appreciated.