# After setting syntax-propertize-function, comment is not being fontified with comment face

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, text-properties, comment, syntax-table

I'm trying to build a major mode for xwiki, where I'm defining

```
{{{
verbatim
}}}
```

as a comment.

So far, I've done

```lisp
    (eval-when-compile
      (defconst xwiki-syntax-propertize-rules
        (syntax-propertize-precompile-rules
         ("{{{" (0 "< b"))
         ("}}}" (0 "> b")))))

     (setq-local syntax-propertize-function (syntax-propertize-rules xwiki-syntax-propertize-rules))
```

When I do `describe-char`, on any of the characters in `{{{`, I see that it is identified as a comment style b. I also see `}}}` identified as comment style b.

However, under text properties, there's nothing set for `face`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Has font-lock even started? Have you defined `font-lock-defaults`?

Comment: I believe so, I did a ```(setq-local font-lock-defaults '(xwiki-mode-font-lock-keywords t))``` in a ```define-derived-mode```, and then I did an ```eval-buffer```, and I switched into another buffer with xwiki text and did ```xwiki-mode```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code will indeed set something for face. @Lindydancer helped me realize that I had set `font-lock-defaults` with the second parameter (`keywords-only`) of the list as `t`).

Unsetting `keywords-only` fixed the above and enabled highlighting.

Also, with

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (defconst xwiki-syntax-propertize-rules
    (syntax-propertize-precompile-rules
     ("{{{" (0 "< b"))
     ("}}}" (0 "> b")))))
```

The last two `}}` did not get fontified with the comment face, but with

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (defconst xwiki-syntax-propertize-rules
    (syntax-propertize-precompile-rules
     ("\\({\\){{" (1 "< b"))
     ("}}\\(}\\)" (1 "> b")))))
```

It gets fontified correctly - `{{{`, `}}}`, and everything between those get fontified as comments.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out! If you are planning to add font-lock keywords, you can use my package `font-lock-studio` to debug them. (It wouldn't have helped in this case, though, since it work for debugging keywords, not the syntactic function.) If you run into more problems, feel free to ask!